# Как растянуть Expander.Header на всю ширину Expander?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Вот как я разметил `Expander.Header`:

```
<Expander.Header>
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Редактировать" Padding="10, 4" FontSize="14"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Expander.Header>
```

Вот результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**

Почему `Grid` не растянулся? И как его растянуть на всю ширину `Expander`?

Comment: так GroupBox.Header или Expander.Header?

Comment: `<Expander.Header>` -> `<Expander.HeaderTemplate>`

Comment: вы хотите чтобы кнопка "Редактировать" была с права?

Comment: @pashagoroshko, да

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, изменил на `HeaderTemplate`, но не помогло. Указал `DataTemplate.Grid`, но он всё ровно не "растягивается"

Comment: Тогда добавляйте гриду нечто такое: `HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=HorizontalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Mode=OneWayToSource}" `

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, помогло, спасибо!

Comment: Ответ сделайте из того, что получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно прописать так:

```
<Expander.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=HorizontalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Expander.HeaderTemplate>
```